# How can we test if an array returns with different length?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I want to test a method with signature `int[] myMethod(int[] array, int removedElement)` as argument. 
The method should remove the element if the element in in the array. As a result, the method may be able to return `int[]` with  `array.length - 1`.

`assertArrayEquals()` does not confirm if the returned array has different length.

`assertNotEquals()` is not appropriate because the method may be removed wrongly more than one element.

How can I test this method?

Comment: Create a new array with the expected value and use `assertArrayEquals` to compare this expected array and the result of the method.

Comment: if all you are wanting to do is test the length of the array why not just use `asserEquals` on `array.length()`. However if you are wanting to test the correct element was removed then Luiggis answer would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects to assert on:

- The length of the array
- The content of the array

It's true that the former will be implicitly tested with the latter, but I prefer to do that explicitly.

This makes it easy: store the length of the input and compare it with the output with `assertEquals()`.

For the latter you take the input array (`new[] { 5, 6 }`) and output (`new[] { 5 }`) and you use `assertArrayEquals()` to compare the output with the result of your method, given the input and argument `6`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the JUnit docs, I found `assertEquals(long, long)`. You should be able to do something like this:

```
Assert.assertEquals("The array length is not what was expected!", (long) array.length - 1, (long) modifiedArray.length);
```

Assuming you're saving your modified array in the `modifiedArray` variable, of course.

(I have little to no experience with JUnit, so I could be totally wrong. If I am, let me know.)

Comment: In JUnit the `assertSame` method tests whether two objects are identical, so this is not the appropriate use for this method. For comparison of two primitive values, the `assertEquals` method is appropriate.

Comment: @Arkanon ...That was a typo. It should be `assertEquals()`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd still test using arrayAssertsEquals, just craft your inputs and expected results using new int[]{}

```
@Test
public void shrinksArray() {
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 2, 3 }, remove(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 1));
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 1, 2 }, remove(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 3));
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 1, 3 }, remove(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 2));
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, remove(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 9));
}
```

Or if you're crazy about single assertions per test...

```
private static final int[] ORIGINAL = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

@Test
public void removesFromBeginning() {
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 2, 3 }, remove(ORIGINAL, 1));
}

@Test
public void removesFromEnd() {
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 1, 2 }, remove(ORIGINAL, 3));
}

@Test
public void removesFromMiddle() {
    assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 1, 3 }, remove(ORIGINAL, 2));
}

@Test
public void doesNotRemoveUnknownItem() {
    assertArrayEquals(ORIGINAL, remove(ORIGINAL, 9));
}
```